# Is grpc server response streaming still blocking?

Tags: python, grpc

I am using a python gRPC client and make request to a service that 
responds a stream. Last checked the document says the iterator.next()
is sync and blocking. Have things changed now ? If not any ideas on overcoming this shortcoming ?
Thanks
Arvind

Comment: What result did you get? Did you get an error? What did .next() return? Please check your console output

Comment: No error, just the gRPC docs show a blocking example and don't mention a nonblocking one like the JavaScript client has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things have not changed; as of 2018-03 the response iterator is still blocking.

We're currently scoping out remedies that may be ready later this year, but for the time being, calling `next(response_iterator)` is only way to draw RPC responses.

Comment: So is it recommended we spawn a thread with the `threading` package to listen for responses? That seems to work for me, just afraid there could be caveats.

Comment: Yep, that's the current recommendation. The caveat is that it costs you a thread, which in some scenarios is more than some developers want to pay.

Answer (score 1):

gRPC now has experimental asynchronous support for Python, and the documentation is here: https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_asyncio.html. You can use an asynchronous iterator over the responses instead of making blocking reads with `next(response_iterator)`.